Why are lights in my home flickering?
I'm having an issue with flickering lights in my home that nobody seems to be able to pin down, and I'm really reaching the end with it. It's frustrating.
The short version of what I've figured out thus far is that high loads on any circuit in the house seem to make the flickering better. I initially thought it was just my HVAC, but it turns out that if my lights are flickering and any high load appliance turns on (my computer (on the same circuit), the oven (different circuit), HVAC (its own circuit)), it gets better or stops.
In the subject room where it's most pronounced, I have these lights that are "dim to warm". Basically instead of just selecting a particular light color/temperature, you can set the light so that as you dim it, the K lowers. Well, I had the dimmer set to the highest brightness just now before this post and when I went to turn my computer on, the brightness immediately increased and the color temperature went up to like 5000K.
I checked the outlets using a multimeter and had normal voltage, at least when I checked. I've changed out the dimmers to make sure they're compatible with my lights. I've tried different lights in the room where it's worst. No joy.
I've had advice that it could be a loose neutral and I had the power company come out. They used a beast or whatever it's called, checked everything everywhere, and all came back clean. The guy was actually really helpful and did me a favor by looking at my panel as well and made sure everything was tightened up and looked good. It did.
Perhaps related to paragraph 2 where I describe the effect of high loads, I tried changing out one of the two lights in the subject room to a regular incandescent bulb. When the regular bulb is not installed, the flickering is there. When I put the regular bulb in place of either LED light, it stops the remaining LED from flickering.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Could you better explain if the flickering only affects LED lights?  And are all of them on dimmers?  Most LEDs on the market are junk and should be expected to flicker at least some of the time.

Thanks for the reply. Yes, it's only affecting the LEDs. They're not the cheapos; they're Halos. I've also tried other brands (Ecosmart, etc). I changed out the dimmer with a higher end, LED compatible switch, too. I have the same LEDs in other rooms in the house with few to no issues.

Maybe a bad circuit.  Try measuring hot-neutral and neutral-ground voltage with and without a large load on the same circuit, like a vacuum or a space heater.

Bad circuit as in the wiring behind the walls or the physical breaker itself? I was reading some more about the elimination of flickering when adding an incandescent in line and folks said something about the switch leaking voltage (deliberately) but I didn't really follow...

So does anyone have any further thoughts on this? I'm out of ideas. I found this thread, but I really don't know what it means...
https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/incandescent-bulb-stops-led-flicker.200789/

Possible cause of flickering LED lights:
Line inductance - LEDs can light with fairly low voltage, low enough that if two electrical runs are parallel and in close contact with each other with one live and the other switch off, the live run will induce voltage into the switched off circuit and if that circuit has an LED, it's lit. The trick of installing an incandescent bulb in a fixure otherwise populated by LEDs resolves the unwanted lighting by providing resistance to the circuit and pulling the voltage down below the value needed to trigger the LED.
Two wire dimmer - There are two types of dimmers available for LEDs - those with effectively 2 connections and those with 3 connections. The 2 connection models have taps for Line and Load. Since the dimmer circuitry requires constant power, the Line side is the input and the Load is the output hence voltage is always available to the LED. The 3 connection model takes the dimmer output voltage and returns it to the breaker box on its own load line.
Possible solution - Have an electrician install Load Resistors for LED Lighting
